# mysqli_stmt_prepare() values sent are null

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have this PHP code here:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
if($resultCheck > 0)
{
   header("Location: ../signup.php?error=userTaken&u&mail=".$email);
   exit();
}
else
{
   $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?,?,?)";
   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
   if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql))
   {
       header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
       exit();
   }
   else
   {
       $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$username,$email,$hashedPwd);
       $bp = $stmt->execute();
       if ( false===$bp )
       {
           die('Error with execute: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
       }
       header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
       exit();
    }
}
```

which gives the error:

```
Error with execute: Column 'uidUsers' cannot be null.
```

the prepared statement doesn't work no matter what I've tried. However, if I use

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (' ',' ',' ')"
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and just insert data without sanitizing it, it works.

Comment: Can't really see any part that you miss out. Are you sure that `$username` is not `null` before insert into the database?

Answer (score 0):

In `if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql))` statement you are executing `$sql` query without bind params. ie you execute `prepare 1st` & then in else you use the `bind`

Use below code :

```
$hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$username,$email,$hashedPwd);

if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
   mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
   if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)>0) //check num rows ie user is available or not
   {
      header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success"); //user available
      exit();
   }
   else
   {
      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror"); //user is not available
      exit();
   }

}
else
{
   die('Error with execute: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));  //Query execution error
}
```

Comment: That just gives me:
    Error with execute: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

So my PHP version was old and didn't support the feature I set it to PHP 7.3 and now the code works.